# how to get output 2 with Fibonacci number in array

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function isPerfectSquare(num)
{
    let n = parseInt(Math.sqrt(num));
    return (n * n == num);
}

// Function to check
// if the number is
// in Fibonacci or not
function checkFib(array, n)
{
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isPerfectSquare(5 * array[i] *
                                array[i] + 4) ||
            isPerfectSquare(5 * array[i] *
                                array[i] - 4))
        {
            console.log(array[i] + " ");
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0)
        console.log("None present + <br>");
}

// Driver Code
let array = [15, 1, ,3];
let n = array.length;

checkFib(array, n);
```

that is function to check nearest fibonaci how to get the output

Question : with Array [ 15, 1, 3 ] Expected Output is 2 because nearest fibonacci of 19 is 21 = 2

Thank u for help. :)

Comment: Can the nearest fibonacci be lower, or is it the *next* fibonacci number (i.e. count upwards until you find one)?

Answer (score 2):

I just write code to get nearest fibonacci, may it should help you. It works !

```
const getNearestFibonacci = (array) => {
  const total = array.reduce((acc, v) => acc + v);

  let fibo = [0, 1];
  do {
    fibo = [...fibo, fibo[fibo.length - 1] + fibo[fibo.length - 2]];
  } while (fibo[fibo.length - 1] < total);

  const afterTotal = fibo[fibo.length - 1];
  const beforeTotal = fibo[fibo.length - 2];

  const next = afterTotal - total;
  const prev = total - beforeTotal;

  return next < prev ? next : prev;
};

console.log("getNearestFibonacci", getNearestFibonacci([15, 1, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks Fibonacci numbers in an array and outputs them. To check nearest Fibonacci, you need a number, why array? Are you summing numbers in array? If yes, then:

- First, add array[i] as `sum = sum + array[i]`
- Then, call `NearestFibonacci (sum)`
  where,

  ```
  NearestFibonacci (int sum){
      if (sum == 0) { 
          cout << 0;
          return;
      }
      int first = 0, mid = 1;
      int last = first + mid;
      while (last <= sum) {
          first = mid;
          mid=last;
          last = first + mid;
      }
      int ans = min(last - sum, sum - mid);
      cout << ans;
  }
  ```

Comment: where is param that is in array ?

can u write a full code to get output 2 ?